# because of Date format im not able to get few records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

For example

```
declare @string varchar(30) = 'dec. 24, 2015'

select substring(@string, 10, 4)

declare @output date

select 
    @output = case 
                 when substring(@string, 1, 3) = 'Dec' 
                   then '12' + '-' + substring(@string, 6, 2) + '-' + substring(@string, 10, 4) 
              end

select convert(varchar(20), @output, 105)
```

Above query I'm getting an output of `24-12-2015` but I have to get other date also from (1 to 31)

Comment: Rolling your own date parsing functions is a Terribad idea

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2012 and above can understand that format when using the PARSE and TRY_PARSE functions, so you don't need to use any custom parsing (which is one of the worst ideas ever):

```
DECLARE @string varchar(30)='dec. 24, 2015'
SELECT TRY_PARSE(@string AS  date USING 'en-US')
```

For more information on parsing and formatting dates with custom date formats, see [this article on SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/88152/).

Answer (score 1):

If your date is always going to be in that format, then you can simply strip the `.` and `,` to get the input in a format that SQL Server can understand.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(30)='dec. 1, 2015';
DECLARE @output DATE;
SELECT @output = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@string, ',', ''), '.','') AS DATE);
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @output, 105);
```